# Separability of group $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be the group $C^*$-algebra of free group $F_n$ of rank $n(n\geq 2)$. Is $A$ separable?

Comment: Isn't the group $C^\ast$-algebra of a discrete countable group $G$ always separable since $\Bbb C[G]$ is dense in $C^\ast(G)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  So long as the group $\Gamma$ is countable, both $C^*(\Gamma)$ and $C_r^*(\Gamma)$ will be separable, as in both cases, those elements of $\mathbb C\Gamma$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$ will be a countable dense subset.

Comment: Please forgive my foolishness. How to show that the free group $F(X)$ is countable ,where $X$ is a finite set. If $X$ is infinite, Is $F(X)$ also countable?

Comment: So long as $X$ is countable, $F(X)$ is countable.   For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $B_n$ denote the collection of those $g\in F(X)$ whose reduced word representation has length at most $n$.  Then each $B_n$ is countable, and $F(X)=\cup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$, therefore $F(X)$ is countable.

Comment: I am confused about the definition of the length of reduced word. If we consider the free group generated by $a$ and $b$.Is the length of reduced word $a^mba$ 3?

Comment: The element $a^mba$ would have length $m+2$.  The length is the number of times you see a generator in the reduced word, and in this example, you see the generator $a$ $m$ times, then $b$ once, then $a$ once more.

Comment: Another way to think of it is via the Cayley graph,  Consider the Cayley graph of the free group $\mathbb F_2$ generated by $a,b$.  Then the length of $g\in\mathbb F_2$ is the length of the path from the identity element to $g$ in this graph.  For more reading, I'd recommend Clara Loh's GTM book on geometric group theory.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: After some consideration, I still confused about the statement those elements of  $ \mathbb C\Gamma$
  with coefficients in Q+iQ will be a countable dense subset. I know the fact that $\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$ is countable, but elements of  $ \mathbb C\Gamma$ are the form of $\sum a_kg_k$, where $a_k\in \Bbb C, g_k\in \Gamma$. How to prove that the elements of the form $\sum q_k g_k$ is countable , where $q_k\in \mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$ .

Comment: There's nothing crazy going on here.  Just use all the ways one can combine countable sets to get countable sets.  Think about it for a while, and if you're still confused, ask a separate question on this site.

Comment: I see . Thanks! May I know your research interest? Would you mind giving me some suggestions on choosing the topics and writing papers. Sometimes I thought of a question, after googling, I found the question has been solved and felt so frustrated.